# Set Up Apache as a Forward Proxy with Caching

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, cache

I would like to configure apache forward proxy with caching. I have some clients that have to downloa some big files from time to time from the internets, and I would like it to be done through this apache proxy, so that it has these big files cached on disk and returns them from cache.

I have managed to configure proxy, but caching does not work. I have *cache*, *mem_cache*, *file_cache* modules enabled. I have the following config of my caching proxy virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from all
</Proxy>

CacheEnable disk /
CacheMaxFileSize 10000000000
CacheMinFileSize 1000000
CacheRoot "/var/cache/apache2/mod_disk_cache/"
CacheMaxExpire 24
CacheLastModifiedFactor 0.1
CacheIgnoreQueryString On
EnableSendfile On
CacheDefaultExpire 7200

CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On
CacheStorePrivate On
CacheStoreNoStore On

ServerName my-proxy

ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/proxy-error.log"
CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/proxy-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

For testing purposes I configured my Firefox to use this proxy. I download a zip file from 
http://download.java.net/jdk8/archive/b128/binaries/jdk-8-fcs-bin-b128-linux-i586-01_feb_2014.tar.gz, which takes about 5 minutes. The only line I get in *proxy-access.log* on this event is:

```
"GET http://download.java.net/jdk8/archive/b128/binaries/jdk-8-fcs-bin-b128-linux-i586-01_feb_2014.tar.gz HTTP/1.1" 200 115883719
```

When I later check the */var/cache/apache2/mod_disk_cache* folder, there is nothing there. And next time I download the same file it also takes the same 5 minutes, although in our local network the speed is much faster - which means it redownloads it from the internet again.

**How can I make it cache?**

I have seen this [Setting Up Apache as a Forward Proxy with Caching](https://serverfault.com/questions/448281/setting-up-apache-as-a-forward-proxy-with-caching) question, read [What Can be Cached?](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html#overview) - there is no "Authorization" header in either request or response (checked with wireshark). So it looks to me as it should be cached. It also should not be affected by [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53787), as apache version is *2.2.22-1ubuntu1* and **not** 2.4.3.

Comment: If your using apache 2.2.22 why did you accept an answer that relates to apache 2.4 ?

Comment: Because it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not initially documented properly, but CacheEnable does not implicitly apply to forward proxy anymore.  there is a note and updated examples now.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cache.html#cacheenable

edit to not hide the answer in the link: as in `CacheEnable disk http://`

Comment: Replacing `CacheEnable disk /` with `CacheEnable disk http://` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I had to specifically do `CacheQuickHandler off`, because of `ProxyPass` inside of `Location`. Caching would not start until this was correct. Example:

```
CacheQuickHandler off                      
CacheRoot /var/cache/apache2

<Location "/wp-content/uploads/_papaya">
    CacheEnable disk
    ProxyPass "https://remote.papaya/wp-content/uploads"
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: The same goes for having:
`CacheEnable disk /myfolder`
It only works if `CacheQuickHandler off`